# flutter firebase filtering streambuilder categories

Tags: firebase, flutter

hello I'm kinda new to Firebase and i have been searching how to filter the streambuilder  based on the category tapped by users sadly i found nothing

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: (searchString == null ||
                            searchString.trim() == '')
                        ? FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('posts')
                            .snapshots()
                        : FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('posts')
                            .orderBy('category')
                            .where('category', isEqualTo: '1')
                            .where('category', isEqualTo: '2')
                            .where('category', isEqualTo: '3')
                            .where('category', isEqualTo: '4')
                            .where('category', isEqualTo: '5')
                            .where('category', isEqualTo: '6')
                            .where('searchKey', arrayContains: searchString)
                            .snapshots(),
```

what should i add to the GestureDetector to link the two together [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XNrS.png)

Answer (score 0):

The .where filter is "And-ed (&&)" with the next one, so in this case your 'category' cannot be equal to '1', and '2' and '3' etc... at the same time.

There are many solutions you could use, like the .where('category',whereIn: ['1','2'])

Comment: I don't understand your following question please clarify. Also if you think my first answer was helpful would appreciate ticking it as solved :)

Comment: i would like to give a user a choice of what type categorize he wants to see by simply pressing a button

Comment: Then as mentioned in the answer, add the categories he presses to an array and then query to get the results that match the categories the user chose .where('category',whereIn: ['1','2'])

Comment: ok but how will link this to onpress to filter the stream-builder on user tap

Comment: You can use setState possibly and pass in a default query in the beginning. When the user choses another filter, set that state and pass in the value the user choses